# How to convert a promise in protractor to a float

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm writing e2e tests using protractor and I'd like to check if some values on the page are correctly calculated. Something very simple like this:

```js
var var1 = element(by.binding('var1'));
var var2 = element(by.binding('var2'));
var var3 = element(by.binding('var3'));

expect(parseFloat(var1.getText())).toEqual(parseFloat(var2.getText()) + 
       parseFloat(var2.getText()));
```

However, because var1, var2 and var3 are all promises, this does not work.

Is there a way of converting the promise object to strings so that I can make the above work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since promises are asynchronous, you can't convert them to a float with a synchronous function. So, you'll need to resolve them. You could do this like:

```
element(by.binding('var1').getText().then(function(text1) {
  element(by.binding('var2').getText().then(function (text2) {
    element(by.binding('var3').getText().then(function (text3) {
      expect(parseFloat(text1)).toEqual(parseFloat(text2) + parseFloat(text3));
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I write my tests with the following pattern:

```
var data = {};
element(by.binding('var1')).getText().then(function(value) { data.var1text = value; });
element(by.binding('var2')).getText().then(function(value) { data.var2text = value; });
element(by.binding('var3')).getText().then(function(value) { data.var3text = value; });
expect(parseFloat(data.var1text)).toEqual(parseFloat(data.var2text) + parseFloat(data.var3text));
```

The pattern is rather short and clear, and all the values from the promises are available for further analysis.

Comment: if the .getText() takes a time (try with e.g. .click() between the calls), the expect() function will receive empty values. So its a bad example.

Answer (score 0):

@jmr : what about using the Runs / WaitsFor mechanisms from Jasmine?, it seems to me to be a bit more standard :

```
var var1, var2, var2 = null;

runs(function() {
  element(by.binding('var1')).getText().then(function(value) { var1 = value; });
  element(by.binding('var2')).getText().then(function(value) { var2 = value; });
  element(by.binding('var3')).getText().then(function(value) { var3 = value; });
}); 

waitsFor(function(){
  return var1 !== null && var2 !== null && var3 !== null;
}, 'The values were not filled', 750); 

runs(function() {
  expect(parseFloat(var1.getText())).
    toEqual(parseFloat(var2.getText()) + parseFloat(var2.getText()));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var var1 = element(by.binding('var1'));
var var2 = element(by.binding('var2'));
var var3 = element(by.binding('var3'));

var promises = [
  var1.getText(),
  var2.getText(),
  var3.getText()
];

protractor.promise.all(promises).then(function( results ) {
  expect(parseFloat( results[0] ))
  .toEqual(parseFloat( results[1] ) + parseFloat( results[2] ));
}
```

Found at [Selenium API](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/namespace_webdriver_promise.html). Note: anything these docs call via `webdriver.particularFunction` are called via `protractor.particularFunction` in protractor.js